# Продолжение выполнение цикла после получение данных PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, циклы

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть код:

```php
$file_save = "png";
$mk = new MessageSendKeyboardAttachment();
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `fruit_img` WHERE `id`");

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    //Загрузка изображений в личные сообщения ВК
    $file_load = new PhotoLoadMessage();
    $file_load->config($access_token, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/".$result['id'].".".$file_save);
    $file_load->getInfo()->id;

    //Создание клавиатуры
    $oKeyboard = new KeyboardNew(false, true);

    $oKeyboard->addButton("Сохранить", "1", "positive", 0, 0);
    $oKeyboard->addButton("Удалить", "2", "negative", 0, 1);
    $keyboard = $oKeyboard->getKeyboard();

    //Отправка сообщения
    $mk->send("", "photo{$file_load->getInfo()->owner_id}_{$file_load->getInfo()->id}", $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token);

}
mysqli_free_result($sql);
```

Сам код выполняется и все происходит хорошо. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой. Если у меня (предположим) есть 5 изображений. То при выполнении он отправит сразу 5 изображений.

Можно ли как-то сделать так что бы при выполнении цикла, он переходил ко 2, 3 и т.д. изображениям только после того как пользователь нажмет на одну из двух кнопок.

При этом если нажимается кнопка 1 он выполняет код (пока не написан), а если на 2 он просто удаляет изображение с сервера и базы данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это очень частый вопрос.
И, соответственно, очень частый ответ: [Как работает РНР, где он выполняется?](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#where)

Если в двух словах, то - нет, нельзя.

Comment: Это было ожидаемо =(
А что можете посоветовать, что бы задуманное можно было воплотить в жизнь?

Comment: запрашивать не 5 картинок, а одну. и запоминать что уже вывели, например

Comment: Хм, в принципе... Можно попробовать, спасибо за помощь